# Logitech MX Master mouse doesn't survive restart in Win10

Tags: windows-10, reboot, logitech-mouse

I set my mouse thumb wheel to adjust audio volume. I changed the thumb buttons to other functions. Everything works fine.

Restart Win10. Nothing.

Rerun Logitech software. Everything works.

Rinse, repeat.

How can I make the Logitech options resume after a restart?

Comment: Is there an option in the Logitech software to run at startup?

Comment: @Steven It is being run on startup by default. Otherwise, you can place its shortcut in the startup folder, or change the startup settings in the Task Manager

Comment: I seem to recall reading about something like this, where you need to tell the software to save the device settings to the mouse itself, as this is what 'profile' is actually loaded at start up...

Answer (score 1):

My mouse was losing the keystroke assignments after restarting Win10. After a restart/reboot I would open Logitech Options, see the key assignments configured in the app, but it would not work. I had to reassign the keystroke every time after a restart for it to work.

**Solution:** Run Logitech Options as Administrator when you want to assign the keystrokes to buttons (Maybe the same for other functions).

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users\AppData\Remote\Microsoft\Windows\Start\Startup\ and place a desktop link of the Logitech software in this folder.

Now right click your task bar, choose *Task Manager*, click on *more details* click on *Startup* and check if Logitech is *Enabled* there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Logitech Options software still has the new settings after the restart.

Also, make sure that your settings are set for "All applications" (in the top right corner). I made a similar mistake.